# Android: suddenly, an AAPT error on multi-argument formatted strings

Tags: android

*Similar questions have been answered several times already, and I did check many of those. This is different, please, read on.*

I have a (large) number of strings defined in `strings.xml` with multiple format arguments. For example:

```
<string name="my_fmt_string">%s and also %s</string>
```

This causes an AAPT error

```
AAPT: warn: multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
```

As I stated above, numerous questions about this have been asked and answered in SO. Those answers refer to using positonal syntax (`%1$s`) and `formatted=false`.

Thing is, **those questions go as far back as 2010, while my application is 4 years old and compiled perfectly until I tried it today**. No recent change points to a problem, certainly not since the last time I compiled this -- 3 days ago, on friday.

I have many, *many* formatted strings in my app. Fixing each case is tedious, and even difficult (what about complex formats like `%02d`? what if use a mix of `String.format` and `context.getString(id, ...args)`?).

What's changed? Why is it suddenly failing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay then. OP here.

I walked back git history until I found a valid build. All of the AAPT messages were warnings at that point.

**The old warnings were reported as errors in Android Studio's UI when I introduced a syntax error somewhere else: an unescaped apostrophe (`'` instead of `\'`)**

The endless cascade of errors made this hard to spot, since suddenly dozens upon dozens of strings were reported as failures in the build log. Walking them 1 by 1, I found the one that differed.

So, if you're reading this: disregard these messages, find the other error.

Comment: My issue was defining `tools:context="..."` twice in the same layout file.